# symfony pass arguments to command line script

Tags: php, bash, symfony, command-line

I have been creating web application using symfony, I want to run commande line instead of run URL inside browser.

composer.json:

```
"import-data": [
            "curl http://localhost:8000/importusers?username=client1"
        ]
```

When I run : `composer import-data` it works fine,
but how I can pass client1 as an argument in this command.

thank you.

Comment: You should have a look into `symfony/console` component

Comment: link: https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html